# No admin console, not listening in port when server in STARTING state

Tags: windows-7, configuration, weblogic

I installed a **WebLogic 11g** (10.3.6) server and an application inside it.

When the application is set up correctly, the server enters `STARTING` state (and henceforth I only see my own application's debug messages). But the server is **not** listening on the default port 7001. I **cannot** access either the application or the admin console, although the application appears to be running OK (as per console logs).

When I break the application's configuration, the server throws exceptions *(as expected)* when running the application in `STARTING` state. Then the server starts listening on default port 7001 and enters (changes to) `ADMIN` state. Now I **can** access the admin console and the (albeit broken) application.

**What is going on?!**

- Why does the server only start listening on the port when the application in broken?
- Why is the admin console only accessible when the application is broken?
- Admin Console is on `http://localhost:7001/console`
- Application is on `http://localhost:7001/myapplication`

I have tried each of the following to start the server (after environment setup). All give the same result:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m weblogic.Server
CALL %MW_HOME%\domain\mydomain\bin\startWebLogic.cmd
CALL %MW_HOME%\domain\mydomain\startWebLogic.cmd
```

I have a feeling that I need to run the admin server **separately** from the application server, but I can't figure out if this is true or how to do it. I also feel that the admin server starts listening on the port, and the application server plugs into it. *Is that how it's supposed to work?*

Comment: *Never mind.* The application is taking too long to initialize in correct configuration. It appeared hung when it was processing for a very long time. Not a problem with WebLogic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was found that the application was taking too long to initialize when configured correctly. I misinterpreted it as a problem with WebLogic, but it's actually a problem with the application.

Without enough logging, the application appeared hung when it was in fact going through a loop quite slowly and consuming a lot of time starting up. WebLogic was merely waiting for the application to finish this boot up process.

I optimized the application to skip this long process, and WebLogic started listening to the ports as soon as the application was done booting up. Then I was able to access the properly configured application and the admin console.

Comment: *Just taking this off "unanswered questions" list `:)`*